# In which section should I put this question?

Tags: support

Assume the following table. I want to partition it in a way that it never happens to have elements from Field1 and Field2 which are "connected" (i.e. a and 1, a and 2, b and 1) go to a separate partition.

This is the solution with 3 partitions.

```
ab12, c3, d45
```

Is this kind or problems related to data science? On which section could I place it?

```
+--------+--------+
| Field1 | Field2 |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
| b      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
| b      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
| c      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
| d      | 4      |
+--------+--------+
| d      | 5      |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be more on-topic in either StackOverflow or the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

This would be off-topic here as this is a db-related question and it has nothing to do with data science.

Comment: Thanks. Just to understand.. Data Mining, clustering is not a part of data science?

Comment: The problem is that this isn't [Cluster Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), nor is it data mining. The question above is requesting for a deterministic algorithm which splits entries to multiple sets based on a specific criterion. Clustering in data science aims to establish clusters of data points without a clear outline among them, but with inherent similarities.

Comment: @E_net4: thanks